# Selenium can only find elements after inspect element

Tags: python, jquery, selenium

I am trying to find get all "a" tags from http://elderofziyon.com/ using selenium, but selenium  returns an empty list. If you inspect a hyperlink element and type $("a").length in console jquery give you a number, otherwise $("a") returns null, just like selenium. A Selenium example would be something like this:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get("http://elderofziyon.com/")
cells = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a")
print(cells)
driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Can anyone suggest what could be the issue and how can I solve it (for either selenium or jquery)? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A [mre] would go a long way towards making this conclusively answerable. That means providing a _specific_ page, and specific code, for which this behavior can be observed.

Comment: Just use find elements by tag name. Also use a wait since your right after a page load.

Comment: It's also in an iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To go into the iframe and retrieve all the a tags. Then loop and print all of the ahref tags do this.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/frameset/frame"))
cells = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.TAG_NAME, "a")))
for cell in cells:
    print(cell.get_attribute("href"))
```

Import the following

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, this works. Is there a way to do the same for jquery/js?